# When does "validates" execute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a Objective-c programmer so I am not used to having code outside of methods.

I have a two-part question about Rail's `validates`.

Consider this code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name,  :presence   => true,
                    :length     => { :maximum => 50}

  validates :email, :presence   => true,
                    :format     => { :with => email_regex }.
                    :uniqueness => true

end
```

1. When exactly is the `validates` method executed? Upon instantiating a `User` instance or when its class definition is loaded?
2. When does the `User` actually get validated? When I save the `User` instance or create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the calls within the class definition are called when the class *definition* is executed, not when an instance is created. It is worth mentioning that the variable email_regex is not a instance variable, but rather a local variable to the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

1) These methods are called on the User class itself, and adds validations to its instance objects.

2) When you save them.

PS: You can use [valid_email](https://github.com/hallelujah/valid_email) gem to validate your email addresses.

You can just do this:

```
validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true
```

...after you put `valid_email` on your `Gemfile`.

Comment: You can actually click +1. :P

Comment: hmm did, not sure why it didn't register.

Answer (score 0):

1 - the validation happens as a callback before save/creation of the model.  So you can instantiate the model w/o validation.  However, when you attempt to save it - it will have to pass validation.

2- When does the User actually get validated? When I save the User instance or create it?

User gets validated upon save or create.  You can override this too if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it in the rails console? When I have a question like that I'll often it interactively and see what happens.

```
./script/console
Loading develoment environment (... )
>> #make a user here and see if you can
```

If you try to save a User and the prerequisites you've specified are not met you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

1. validates is executed when the user.rb file is loaded.
2. The user is actually validated when you call #save or #valid?